# How can we apply editable marker for polygon in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am working on polygon distance area,with this i want to add marker and want to get the distance between that, I found code for that, but i am not able to edit that polygon area and not able to add markers, i tried lot but it is not working for me, can anyone please help me for this, how can i resolve this issue ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
      // When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
      // information about the polygon's coordinates.

      var map;
      var infoWindow;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
        var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
            {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
            {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event.
        bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      }

      /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
      function showArrays(event) {
        // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
        // MVCArray of LatLngs.
        var vertices = this.getPath();

        var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
            'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
            '<br>';

        // Iterate over the vertices.
        for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
          var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
          contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
              xy.lng();
        }

        // Replace the info window's content and position.
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYeDBDl-8Wx98Az55EbVnpvRfSIBbwxyE&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try to add markers or edit the Polygon that didn't work? What are you trying to add to the posted code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add markers, edit your script and place this code under triangleCoords:

```
// Add Markers to Coordinates
    for(var i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
      var pos = triangleCoords[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        draggable: true
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

To do some specific with markers, go here: [Learn About Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)
To get distance, use Distance Matrix: [Learn About Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

Hope that helps you get moving.
JSBin: [copy of your code w/ marker](https://jsbin.com/mukuwoj/4/edit?js,output)

Comment: thanks a lot, can you help me how can we drag this marker ?, so i can change the area

Comment: Just add 'draggable' option to your marker options. I edited the code to include 'draggable'. Learn more about Marker options: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#draggable][1]

Comment: JavaScript V3 Reference (MarkerOption Properties) - [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#MarkerOptions]